# Java.util.NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Codechef
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   int T= in.nextInt();

   for(int k=0;k<T;)
   {
     int M=in.nextInt();
     int N=in.nextInt();
     int product=M*N;
     Double result=0.0;
     for(int i=2;i<product/2;i++)
     {
       if((product%Math.pow(i,2))==0)
       {
        result=product/Math.pow(i,2);
       }
     }
     System.out.println(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Input:

> 2
>
> 10 15
>
> 9 3

Output:

> 6.0
>
> 3.0

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
> at Codechef.main(Main.java:18)

My program actually prints the minimum squares that can be made from the given
length*breadth dimension
my code is working fine when i am taking input once but i want to take as many inputs as the user wants,for this i have applied for loop before taking input M and N but it throws runtime error now although it works fine without that for loop in line:15
any help would be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: No errors in your code. It might be how the server loads your program

Comment: i am trying to submit my code to codechef.com and it says your program have runtime errors.

Comment: Why are you taking `T` as input? Because you aren't using it. You are missing `for(int k=0; k<T; k++)` k++, try with this.

Comment: i have used T actually in the for loop and yes code worked after adding k++, i thought because  i am not using the value of k anywhere inside the loop so there is no need to increment k.i was wrong thank you brother for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your loop will be infinite, as you haven't increased your counter.
And since that is an infinite loop it exhausts your input, which is the reason for that exception.

add k++ in the first loop, like you have i++ in the second loop.
That should fix it.

Comment: thank you brother ,that fixed it i thought since i am not using the value of k anywhere inside the loop so may be there is no need to increment k i was wrong tho.

Comment: Can you select my answer as the one that worked for you?